# Changes on default controller leads to 404 Page Not Found

Tags: routes, codeigniter-3

I changed default controller to point to my own controller but it will leads to 404 Page Not Found. I change back the default controller and it works just fine.

I tried on changing the .htaccess

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'public_c/home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['home'] = 'public_c/home';
```

i expect when i removed the index.php in my url, it will point to the public_c/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put you default controller inside a directory under `controllers` .. if you must you have two options .. first redirection which you can create a default controller directly under `controllers` directory and then redirect to your `public_c/home` .. and secondly (not preferable at all unless you extend the core) modifying systems's router.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i dint know that default controller cannot link inside a directory under controller. i add in redirect('index.php/home'); under my welcome controller